# how to deploy and run oozie job?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

I'm trying to do a simple job using oozie. 
 It will be a one simple Pig Action.

I have a file : FirstScript.pig containing:

```
dual = LOAD 'default.dual' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
store dual into 'dummy_file.txt' using PigStorage();
```

and a workflow.xml containing:

```
<workflow-app name="FirstWorkFlow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2">
    <start to="FirstJob"/> 
    <action name="FirstJob">
        <pig>
            <job-tracker>hadoop:50300</job-tracker>
            <name-node>hdfs://hadoop:8020</name-node>
            <script>/FirstScript.pig</script>
        </pig>
        <ok to="okjob"/>
        <error to="errorjob"/>
    </action>
    <ok name='okjob'>    
        <message>job OK, message[${wf:errorMessage()}]</message>
    </ok>    
    <error name='errorjob'>    
        <message>job error, error message[${wf:errorMessage()}]</message>
    </error>    
</workflow-app>
```

I have created structure :

```
FirstScript
|- lib
|---FirstScript.pig
|- workflow.xml
```

And what now?
How do I deploy it and run with oozie? 
Can anyone more experienced help?

Regards
Pawel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
hadoop fs -put workflow.xml some_dir/ 
oozie job --oozie http://your_host:11000/oozie -config cluster_conf.xml -run
```

and my cluster_conf.xml looks like this (please check your ports first they depend on Hadoop distro):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>nameNode</name>
        <value>hdfs://my_nn:8020</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>jobTracker</name>
        <value>my_jt:8050</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>oozie.wf.application.path</name>
        <value>/user/my_user/some_dir/workflow.xml</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer. Two more questions: should this cluster_conf.xml file also be uploaded to hdfs? And second: because i haven't done the installation, i'm not sure about the address of my oozie installation. Whre can i find it? I know that configuration required for  cluster_conf.xml can be found in core-site.xml and  mapred-site.xml, but there is nothing about oozie...

Comment: Hi, I'm glad it helped. No you don't need to copy this conf file to hdfs. And you can find Oozie config in **oozie-site.xml** ;) In my installation it's in  **/etc/oozie/conf/oozie-site.xml**, just look for **oozie.base.url** property.

Answer (score 2):

Config file should point to job.properties in place of `file.xml`. Since, `job.properties` contains path to `workflow.xml`

```
oozie job --oozie http://your_host:11000/oozie -config **/job.properties** -run
```